# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 two dimensional array

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

I keep getting this error when I try to run my program but I already accounted for the size and starting at the 0 index.

```js
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        int z =6;
        int[][] num = new int [4][4];
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++){
           for (int x =0; x < 4; i++){
                num[i][x]=z;
                System.out.println(num[i][x]);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `(int x =0; x < 4; i++)` see what you did there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nested for loop, you are incrementing `i` instead of `x`.

```
 for (int x =0; x < 4; i++) { }
```

needs to be

```
 for (int x =0; x < 4; x++) { }
```